# How I can change the default ephemeral storage in Rancher

Tags: kubernetes, storage, rancher, ephemeral-storage

How I can change the default ephemeral storage in Rancher.

Suppose current ephemeral storage is using /dev/sda1 so I want to change it to /dev/sda2. Any document or steps will be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There are things to consider in achieving your use case. To start off, you need to change the kubelet ‘–root-dir’ setting. In your case make sure that the directory /dev/sda2 is mounted and formatted. Go to Rancher and modify the cluster configuration and adjust the parameters. In the Extra Args or Extra Binds field, adjust the ‘--root-dir’ parameter to point to your new mount point. Once completed ensure that /dev/sda2 is properly formatted and mounted, restart the services to make sure the changes would take effect. Attached are documentations for good read.[1][2]

[1] https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/

[2]

https://ranchermanager.docs.rancher.com/v2.5/reference-guides/cluster-configuration/rancher-server-configuration/rke1-cluster-configuration